# how to add an active admin field for a postgres jsonb field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activeadmin

While this works with the jsonb field:

```
step.title['en'] = 'Lorem'
step.save
step.title
=> {"en"=>"Lorem"}
```

The following doesn't

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs name: 'Title', for: :title do |t|
    t.input :en, input_html: { value: f.object.title['en'] } if f.object.present?
    end
  end
end
```

Re asking based on this question cos answer doesn't seem to work for my case: [Unable to find input class for json - handling JSON type in Active Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22787096/unable-to-find-input-class-for-json-handling-json-type-in-active-admin)

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out using the link from your original question.

This is what mine looks like:

**admin/client.rb**

```
permit_params :name, settings: [ Client.storext_definitions.keys ]

f.inputs name: "Client Settings", for: :settings do |s|
  s.input :status_for_map, as: :select, collection: options_for_select( Order.statuses.map{ |status, id| [status.humanize, status] }, client.settings['status_for_map'])
  s.input :time_zone, input_html: { value: "#{client.settings['time_zone']}" }
end
```

Hopefully that helps you or anyone following up.